# What are the risks associated with solely relying on freelancing income and making it as a career?

Tags: legal, attracting-clients, foreign-markets

With cheap and quality work available over dozens of freelancing sites, Does the world of freelancing comes with risks like ban by the USA government on outsourcing of jobs and offshore freelancing ? Apart from these what are some other risks a freelancer should be aware of and be prepared?

Comment: Apart from the fluctuating income, you mean?

Comment: even fluctuating income can become a problem

Comment: This is a very open question, and could have pages and pages of answers. Can you try to make it more specific so this can be answered more easily?

Answer (score 3):

Working for yourself always is more risky than it is to have a stable job working for someone else.  The business owner always absorbs the risk of the company.  The worker simply gets his due.  The big risk is that of income instability, and this is something every self-employed individual faces all the time.  This is one reason we have to charge more than we would if we worked a steady job.

The second issue has to do with legal risk though and this is what I think you are asking about.  Will there ever be an outright ban on self-employment in the US, especially in the knowledge services sector?  I seriously doubt it.  There is unlikely to be a ban of the sort that came into effect regarding handmade children's toys.  However the general trend is towards more and more regulation which unduly burdens the self-employed in pursuit if a perfectly regulated society.  These are problems when they do not take into account the realities of self-employment and expect greater financial burdens (PPACA) or regulatory compliance burdens which the self-employed are in the worst position in the economy to meet.  Part of the problem is that one part of our political system appears to believe that the economy is best served by the triplicity of big business, big regulation, and big labor.

I know I sound like a right-winger when I say the above, but it is very much a concern for self-employed and now I will sound like a left-winger by pointing out that while Americans are finding it harder to be self-employed, the same is *not* true in Canada and Europe, where often times regulation is differently structured and the self-employed small business owners are more likely to be successful, so the fundamental problem is that the regulatory burdens tend to assume that they should apply in the same way to the self-employed as to the multi-national corporation (the result of which is not always pleasant for the self-employed).  So the problem is not only that we overregulate but how we regulate.

Speaking of legal issues one serious issue that freelancers in the US need to be aware of regarding legal risk is the effort to ensure that sales taxes are collectable across state lines, with each tax jurisdiction (i.e. school district) able to decide what the tax rates are and for what.  Such efforts effectively bury the self-employed who work remotely who don't really have the time to verify whether that $120 tech support call from Akron Ohio is taxable and at what rate (big businesses on the other hand have dedicated staff to handle this sort of thing).  You may think that software services are not taxable, but there have been efforts to expand sales taxes to these areas.  A few years ago a bill was proposed in the Washington State legislature that would have done exactly this, but thankfully failed.  I don't see so-called streamlined sales taxes dying and there are renewed efforts to get Congress to make such taxes owed whenever business is done across state lines.  One major risk is that Congress will pass such a law and then we really will have to determine whether each service we offer is taxable in every jurisdiction we offer it.  Additionally even if the SSTI folks claim that common tax definitions across state lines remove a lot of the headache (and lead to Snickers being taxed as candy while Twix is merely a chocolate-covered cookie, so a tax on candy bars will hit snickers and chocolate bars, but not kit kats or twix), there is no guarantee that courts interpreting the definitions will not diverge one jurisdiction to another.

Answer (score 0):

As for USA, I wouldn't so concerned about the possibility of such ban. USA government is concentrated more on the gain of its big business than the protection of own workers. Europe cares more about it, but still I can't imagine such radical move. Even if it would happen, it's almost improbable that the incorporation of Juche doctrine would follow and the buying of products abroad would be forbidden. The companies would build their filiae abroad, so the external freelancers would still have a job.

I would be more concerned about the possibility of your country forbidding freelancing or any other kind of business. In last country only 2 countries have chosen isolation : North Korea and Albania. Many more have chosen the communistic method of development.

No matter what will happen to your freelancing, the experience you gather counts. So you can always put freelancing experience in your CV and have a chance for career as employee.